# FastAPI relationship two tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Good Day

I have to tables: tblAssets & tblAssetTypes.  tblAssets is the main table and contains a column assetType that is an integer and is linked to tblAssetTypes id column.  I have defined the models as follows:

```
class Assets(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblAssets"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    assetName = Column(String)
    assetType = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tblAssetTypes.id"))
    assetCategory = Column(Integer)
    assetSerial = Column(String(50), unique=True, index=True)
    assetLabel = Column(String(50), unique=True, index=True)
    assetUser = Column(Integer)
    primaryLocation = Column(String)
    secondaryLocation = Column(String)
    assetStatus = Column(String)
    assetValue = Column(Float)
    assetCondition = Column(Integer)
    assetQuantity = Column(Integer)

    two = relationship("AssetTypes", back_populates="one")

class AssetTypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblAssetTypes"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    assetType = Column(String)

    one = relationship("Assets", back_populates="two")
```

Currently, I am receiving results as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "assetType": 1,
    "assetSerial": "SERIAL",
    "assetUser": 1,
    "primaryLocation": "South Afric",
    "assetStatus": "A",
    "assetCondition": 10,
    "assetCategory": 1,
    "assetName": "Apple MacBook Pro 13 inch",
    "assetLabel": "MP-SA-LP-01",
    "secondaryLocation": "ASF",
    "assetValue": 30000,
    "assetQuantity": 1
  }
]
```

I would like to do an "inner join" where it replaces the assetType id with the assetType name.

I have tried checking other StackOverflow questions for a solution but I was not able to find a solution to my issue.

Any help with this would be appreciated and if I haven't provided enough information, I am more than willing to provide more.

Answer (score 0):

Defining your schema in pydantic will save you

```
class AssetBase(BaseModel):
  assetName: Optional[str] = None
  ...

class AssetTypesBase(BaseModel):
  assetType: Optional[str] = None
```

for relationship purpose you will need to define the specific data to pull and define your relationship key and since it seems you are pulling the asset table model you can specify the key in the AssetInDB class and have it reference a class in AsssetTypeNameInDB class which has the name already

```
class AssetInDB(BaseModel):
  two: List[AsssetTypeNameInDB]

  class Config:
   orm_mode = True
   allow_population_by_field_name = True

class AsssetTypeNameInDB(BaseModel):
  assetType: str

  class Config:
   orm_mode = True
   allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

Whether in the same python class it should work but if you separate your schemas, remember to import your classes and import from typing Optional and List classes

```
from typing import List, Optional
```

This [Tiangolo fastapi documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) and [Jetbrains Tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tutorials/fastapi-aws-kubernetes/rest_api_5/) should help explain further